# Make a solid box (cube) in ILNumerics

Tags: c#, 3d, plot, cube, ilnumerics

I want to make a solid box with ILNumerics. As I read in the documentation website, there is only a way to make a sphere object. I want a box (cube).

I just read this thread: [ILNumerics plot a plane at specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617265/ilnumerics-plot-a-plane-at-specific-location) . Then I have an idea to make 6 plane then arrange them as a box.

But it is seems an empty box. I want a solid box. Are there any idea to do this?
I will duplicate this box to make many of them for the further work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Most Simple Solution

In the (barely documented) `ILNumerics.Drawing.Shapes` class you can find an `UnitCubeFilled` shape and its wireframe version:

```
private void ilPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ilpanel1.Scene.Camera.Add(Shapes.UnitCubeFilled);
    ilpanel1.Scene.Camera.Add(Shapes.UnitCubeWireframe);
    ilpanel1.Scene.First<ILTriangles>().AutoNormals = false; 
    ilpanel1.Configure();
}
```

Note, all edges of the cube share the only 8 vertices in the shape. Therefore, the lighting normals are shared and interpolated between all edges which would cause any lighting to look unnatural. Thats why I deactivated the light by disabling the auto normals creation.

You can easily reuse those shapes - their storage is shared by ILNumerics under the hood. In large setups you would place several of these shapes under individual `ILGroup` nodes. The groups are used in order to relocate and rotate the shapes accordingly.

### Advanced Solution

The `Shapes.UnitCubeFilled` focusses on a cheap setup. If you need individual colors for the sides or a better lighting, you need to assemble the cube from individual vertices for each edge. Basically, what one would do:

- Start with a fresh `ILTriangles` shape
- Give it 24 vertices: 4 for each side
- Create 24 color entries with individual color information for the sides

A simple example could look as follows:

[image]

This is the code for the front and right side. The other sides are left as an exercise... ;)

```
ilpanel1.Scene.Camera.Add(new ILTriangles("tri")
{
    Positions = new float[,] { 
        // front side
        {0,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,0},
        {0,0,0},{1,1,0},{0,1,0},
        // right side
        {1,0,0},{1,0,-1},{1,1,-1},
        {1,0,0},{1,1,-1},{1,1,0},
    },
    Colors = new float[,] { 
        // front side
        {0,0,1},{0,0,1},{0,0,1},
        {0,0,1},{0,0,1},{0,0,1},
        // right side
        {0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},
        {0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},
    }
}); 
ilpanel1.Configure();
```

Comment: Yes. This is that I want. Thank you dude. You saved me!